# facebook fan page cannot be crawled

Tags: facebook, web-crawler

I want to crawl the fan page comments on the Facebook by using python. I go to the Graph API explorer to get the user token. After I submit the request "fanpage_name ?fields=id,name", I get this error message -->
(#10) To use 'Page Public Content Access', your use of this endpoint must be reviewed and approved by Facebook. To submit this 'Page Public Content Access' feature for review please read our documentation on reviewable features: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review.
However, if I sent the request of my id "my_id ?fields=id,name", it can work well. Is the fan page not be crawled now due to privacy problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you own the page, just use a Page Token. If you don´t own the Page, you can use an App Token - User Tokens are for user content.

For Pages you don´t own, you need to get reviewed by Facebook. That´s what the error message tells you.